# Can`t "add view" from Controller/Action in VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

this might be a dumb question:

In previous VS versions, one could "Add View" by right-clicking in the View portion of the code as shown below.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

In VS2013/MVC5 (apparently) this options does not exist. Anyone knows how to find it, or know how to do it?

I noticed some strange behaviors:
1) When I create a new Controller through Scaffold... MVC5 Empty Controller, the corresponding view/folder is not created
2) If I try to Scaffold... MVC5 View, there is no place where one can inform the corresponding Controller

This is weird...

Thanks!!

Comment: Try upgrading to the RTM version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to fix this today after much searching for: C# MVC5.1.2, EF 6.1.0 in VS2013 Express for Web.  Be aware that this is VS2013 Update 2 RC (<-----note Release Candidate)

This is a very large update so VS2013 and all projects were closed.

see:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307 
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes

Both Add Controller and Add View are back in the context menus and have worked on my test projects.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Dresko pointed out, the version I was using was RC and obviously I did not notice that before.
One should use the RTM or above version to get this fixed.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just two steps

1)[Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41204) your Visual studio 2013

2) unload your project from solution explorer then Reload it again.

Bingo!